# Dart: How to iterate digits of integer?

Tags: dart

How to iterate digits of integer? for example sum of digits here, it works, but is any way to right way?

```
int sumOfDigits(int num) {
  int sum = 0;
  String numtostr = num.toString();
  for (var i = 0; i < numtostr.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + int.parse(numtostr[i]);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly inefficient to create a string, then split the string, and parse the individual digits back to integers.

How about something like:

```dart
Iterable<int> digitsOf(int number) sync* {
  do {
    yield = number.remainder(10);
    number ~/= 10;
  } while (number != 0);
}
```

This iterates the digits of the (non-negative) number in base 10, from least significant to most significant, without allocating any strings along the way.

If you want the digits in the reverse order, you can either create a list from the iterable above and reverse it, or use a different approach:

```dart
Iterable<int> digitsHighToLow(int number) sync* {
  var base = 1;
  while (base * 10 < number) {
    base = base * 10;
  }
  do {
    var digit = number ~/ base;
    yield digit;
    number = (number - digit * base) * 10;
  } while (number != 0);
}
```

(again, only works on non-negative numbers, you'll have to figure out what you want for negative numbers, either throw, or try negating the number, it's the same digits after all, or something else).

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a shorter way to do this, you can combine [split](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/String/split.html), [map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) and [reduce](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html)

```
int sum = num.split('').map((e) => int.parse(e)).reduce((t, e) => t + e);
```

You can even do this:

```
int sum = num.split('').map(int.parse).reduce((t, e) => t + e);
```

Thank you @julemand101

Comment: You can make it even shorter by using `map(int.parse)` instead of `map((e) => int.parse(e))`

Comment: And just for fun (since the readability are not that great) you can use the following where we don't even need to call `int.parse`: `int sum = num.codeUnits.reduce((a, b) => a + b - 48) - 48;` since we know the codeUnit 48 is the ASCII code for `0`.